# Xtend for loop (desired while loop function)

Tags: for-loop, while-loop, xtend

I have some Xtend code that outputs data. Here is the code below:

```
«FOR a:e.attributes»
    «a.eClass.name» «a.name»,
«ENDFOR»
```

This would output something like:

```
ClassName name1, ClassName name2, ClassName name3, ClassName name4,
```

My Desired Output is:

```
ClassName name1, ClassName name2, ClassName name3, ClassName name4
```

Note that there is no comma at the end of the line on the desired output. Is it possible to implement a function in Xtend that will allow me to not output the last comma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`«FOR a:e.attributes SEPARATOR ', '»«a.eClass.name» «a.name»«ENDFOR»`

or even

`e.attributes.map['''«eClass.name» «name»'''].join(', ')`

Comment: Thank you very much this is what I was looking for but I still have a problem. How would I output the following?

    ClassName name2, ClassName name3, ClassName name4

Comment: I'm struggling to see how that differs from your original question. If you mean "without the first attribute's info" then `... e.attributes.tail ...`, or perhaps you mean `...', '»ClassName «a.eClass.name» ...`